# Creating a main account twilio client on a subaccount node function

Tags: node.js, twilio, serverless

I'm developing a twilio function on a subaccount that needs to acces a twilio client on the main account. The function is being deployed through a Github action to the subaccount.

For this, on the subaccount function I have:

```js
const mainClient = new twilio(context.MAIN_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, context.MAIN_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

Then I need to access serverless.services but I'm getting serverless undefined therefore can't access services.

i.e.

```
return mainClient.serverless.services(...
```

I tested code locally and it worked but failed on deployment. Is it possible to access services on main account from a subaccount function??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone experiencing a similar issue.

My problem was that deploying without being explicit about dependencies doesnt install the latests version of dependencies.

Deploy through github installed twilio node sdk version 3.29.0 but this version doesn includes serverless api yet. So I explicitly added latest twilio node sdk (3.75.0 at the moment) and that fixed the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted and thanks for sharing the answer!